# Understanding multi-displays, multi GPUs in Windows 10

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, windows-10, gpu

My laptop has two GPUs: an NVidia GT630M and an integrated Intel HD4000. Both are able, on their own, to drive up to two displays. I thought that, wow, I could use three displays with my laptop (the laptop screen, a first monitor via an HDMI port and a second via a VGA port).

Now, if I understand correctly, to my dismay it seems that Windows 10 cannot automatically tell one of the the GPU to drive a display and the other GPU to drive two displays. In another question on this site, [an user says](https://superuser.com/a/442145/327281) that one needs a SLI setup in order to do so. On the other hand, it seems that some [Linux distros](https://superuser.com/questions/867333/multi-gpu-for-3rd-monitor-linux-mint-geforce-750ti) are able to manage the setup without SLI.

Why is it not possible in Windows? I assume it has to do with how Windows handles and distribute a graphic load to the GPUs, but I am not certain. If someone has a detailed answer, I would be glad to better understand how the OS works...

Comment: This boils down to you requiring a driver.  Intel dropped the ball on supporting Windows 10 your only real choice wait until they pick it up.

Comment: Does it mean that I could have done what I wanted with Windows 8.1?

Comment: Its possible if you had drivers installed it would work.  But honestly based on the link answer, I don't see how you conclude, it even should be possible.  You don't have SLI so that isn't even possible, and its not possible to connect your iGPU to your dGPU.

Comment: OK I will try to get more info on what is SLI in details since it seems that I make incorrect assumptions. Thanks!